# APScheduler with win32com

Tags: python, win32com, apscheduler

I am trying to run a script at set times daily that utilizes the win32com library.  I have tried using both Outlook and Excel functions but am receiving an error:

It kicks off just fine, and it will run tasks that do not use win32com....

Any suggestions??

```
logging.basicConfig()
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()

def email_Task():
    obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")  <---- Problem line
    olMailItem = 0x0
    newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    newMail.Subject = "Hello"
    newMail.Body = ""
    newMail.To = "xyz123@gmail.com"
    newMail.Send()
sched.add_cron_job(email_Task, day_of_week='mon-fri',hour=08,minute=00,second=00)
```

Comment: Also, is the script running under your user GUI session, or is it being launched by a service or something? Because you can't use the `Dispatch` interface to script most GUI apps from outside the same GUI session. If you're running under a _different_ session, you can use `DispatchEx` to create an Excel instance in that different session instead of trying to control the one in the desktop session. If you're not running under a GUI session at all, you basically can't do this.

Comment: I was having this same issue. I switched to the `schedule` module and that now works.